# Copy and duplicate rows based on condition

Tags: r

My Dataframe looks similar to this

```
 Date   Key  Value1  Value2
   D1   1A     2
   D1   2A     1      2
   D2   3B     1      3
   D2   1A     3
   D3   2A     5
```

As you can see, the `Key`itself ain't primary, However if we consider `Date`and `Key`together, each observation finds it as a primary key. 
Now I wish to achieve that for every observation where `Value1`and `Value2`both are present, duplicate the row and break them into two rows. Something like this:

```
Date   Key  Value1  Value2  Value
D1     1A     2               2
D1     2A     1       2       1
D1     2A     1       2       2
D2     3B     1       3       1
D2     3B     1       3       3
D3     2A     5               5
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `Value` column you are after? Maybe consider [reshaping wide-to-long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252)?

Comment: I tried melt(), the problem is, my no. of columns in the actual dataframe is close to 30 and almost 200,000 rows. Hence melting with the columns got messy. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Could you share the code you have used to melt?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
df %>% gather(keys,Value,-Date,-Key) %>% filter(!is.na(Value)) %>% arrange(Date,Key)

  Date Key   keys Value
1   D1  1A Value1     2
2   D1  2A Value1     1
3   D1  2A Value2     2
4   D2  1A Value1     3
5   D2  3B Value1     1
6   D2  3B Value2     3
7   D3  2A Value1     5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Value3 = ifelse(is.na(Value2),list(Value1),list(c(Value1,Value2)))) %>%
  unnest

# # A tibble: 7 x 5
#    Date   Key Value1 Value2 Value3
#   <chr> <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1    D1    1A      2     NA      2
# 2    D1    2A      1      2      1
# 3    D1    2A      1      2      2
# 4    D2    3B      1      3      1
# 5    D2    3B      1      3      3
# 6    D2    1A      3     NA      3
# 7    D3    2A      5     NA      5
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="
Date   Key  Value1  Value2
D1   1A     2      NA
D1   2A     1      2
D2   3B     1      3
D2   1A     3      NA
D3   2A     5      NA",h=T,strin=F
)
```